# How to handle log data within documents (articles)?

Tags: formatting, packages

I have to add the log-output of a program to the appendix of my article. A verbatim-block was my first choice, but the single lines are to long (far more than 80 characters) and therefore the lines "overflow" and the whole output does not fit on the page.

Is there some existing library or command or something similar to import a log-file? It should be able to break the lines automatically. The containing entries look like  apache error or access log messages.

Comment: Why not simply put it in the page as normal text, maybe using a `tt` font. Are there any characters in the logs that could *confuse* LaTeX? (some of the usual suspects would be `$`, `#` or `_`)

Comment: Would shrinking the size of the verbatim block solve the problem, or are the lines so long that line breaking is essential?

Comment: Listings package could do.

Comment: Is there any news here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package `listings` can do the job.

[image: nanListings]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[lastline=5]{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.log}
\lstset{breaklines=true}
Line breaks enabled:
\lstinputlisting[lastline=5]{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.log}
\end{document}
```